# NSButton on NSVisualEffectView: Wrong Background Color

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsview, nsbutton, nsvisualeffectview

I have a **NSVisualEffectView** within a **NSPopover** developed for **10.10**.

When subclassing the **NSVisualEffectView** to have hover background color effect, the borderless button color seems to be different

[image: gray box]

I tried setting the `backgroundColor` of the button cell to `clearColor` or the same as I used in `drawRect:` in of the **NSVisualEffectView**, the former gives wrong color (not filled with blue) and the later still the same with wrong color. (gray box around its border).

`CALayer` can fix this but is there a way without using it?

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you subclassing NSVisualEffectView?

Comment: Got my reasons but the same will happen when using NSView, so it's NSVisualEffectView or NSView seems not related to the question?

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: You mention "`CALayer` can fix this". Can you elaborate? I'm willing to try that fix on my project.

Answer (score 3):

After much trial and error, this worked for me:

```
button.wantsLayer = true
button.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor().CGColor
```

I've got an NSTableView with NSVisualEffectView style. I created a custom NSTableViewCell class and put these lines in its drawRect method.

Comment: As I no longer have a working project to verify this (thanks to the syntax changes made in Swift 2), I'll give you an upvote for your effort. I assume this will work as, after a year more in being a developer, seems most drawing issues can be solved by utilizing the CA layer (`.wantsLayer`). However, since this is SO, until someone can confirm it, I can't mark this as an answer.

Comment: I happened to have another project that came across this issue. Seems that this will not always fix the problem, e.g. place a button on a NSImageView. Still looking for solutions once for all.

Comment: I tried this, even `CGColor.clear`, and it has no effect

Comment: I added a image to the button there is a way to make it with vibrancy effect?

Answer (score 0):

This has been open for a long time but I just needed the answer myself and maybe someone else is happy to find this here, answer works only for Mac OS 10.14 and up

`button.contentTintColor = .white`

By setting the contetTintColor to whatever you might need it will for some reason remove the background color.