# Remove Background From NSButton

Tags: swift, nsbutton

Hey so i have a table view embeded in a visual effect view, in one of the rows i have a save button and the save button every time i click the cell gets this funky background color around it.
[image]

Iv tried

```
saveButton.wantsLayer = true
saveButton.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor.CGColor
```

but that doesnt work, on the things like labels and stuff the same thing happened but i was able to fix it by setting the background color to a color then turning the opacity all the way down. But because its a button that doesnt work! Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any background image in your button?

Comment: nope! All i did was drag an drop a UIButton into the cell, it doesnt show up when the cell isnt selected but when it is selected it shows up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSButton on NSVisualEffectView: Wrong Background Color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659384/nsbutton-on-nsvisualeffectview-wrong-background-color)

Answer (score 3):

If someone still gets stuck on this, seems like setting `isBordered` to `false` does the trick.

```swift
saveButton.wantsLayer = true
saveButton.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor.CGColor

saveButton.isBordered = false // This does the trick.
```